# Getting different objects from factory

Tags: jakarta-ee, seam

in my Bean I have the following code shown below.

What I want: I'd like to get every time, when I call the factory a new random person-List.

What I get: I do get every time the same person-list. The obviously reason is, that the factory method only creates a new object, if the current object is null i.e. only at the first factory call.

How do I have to change the code, that I get a new object every time?

Thank you!

```
@Logger                  private Log log;
@In                      private EntityManager entityManager;
@In                      private LocaleSelector localeSelector;

@Factory("personList")
public List<Person> createPersonList() {
    log.info("Creating Person List.");

    return entityManager.createQuery(
    "SELECT p FROM Person p ORDER by random()")
    .setMaxResults(3)
    .getResultList();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the METHOD scope:

```
@Factory(value="personList", scope=ScopeType.METHOD)
public List<Person> createPersonList() {
```

Technically, the METHOD scope is meant for internal use, though, so if a new list for each HTTP request is acceptable, I'd use `ScopeType.EVENT`.